# Stationarity iff causal and invertible

Tags: time-series, arima, stationarity

Suppose $X_t$ is an ARMA(p,q) process.

Is it true to say: "$X_t$ is weakly stationary iff $X_t$ is causal and invertible"?

If so, why? If not, is there something similar?